# Compiling httperf on Mac

Tags: macos, httperf

Wondering if anyone can tell what's going on? After slogging through compilation trial and error all day, I've got a httperf that compiles and runs yet fails to connect to anything. It now barfs with "httperf: can't open google.com".

My guess is that the problem has something to do with setting a high maxfiles limit, but I have no idea why. I had to do `ulimit -n` because httperf kept barfing with "httperf: failed to increase number of open file limit". (The homebrew version I installed a long time ago also barfs with this error).

If you look at the source, the system `open()` call is failing. Why? Why???
https://github.com/httperf/httperf/blob/ab2b96b0f5988c790de5cbc757dfd928c728f4da/src/conn.c#L65

Mac OSX version is 10.9.5.

My steps:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65535 65535
ulimit -n 65535

git clone https://github.com/httperf/httperf
cd httperf
glibtoolize --force
aclocal
autoconf
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
make install
cd ../
autoreconf -i
```

Uggghhhhhhhh.